# Menu collapse with jQuery and a button to toggle the collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Here is what I am trying to achieve

- A menu that would collapse into a smaller menu if window size < 768px
- The menu would restore to its original size again when window size > 768 px
- There is a button to toggle the collapse of the menu

This is how I try to tackle the problem: http://jsbin.com/vefopuka/1/edit

But I find out that while the menu does change its size (or class) upon screen size change, the button won't toggle the collapse of the menu.

Is there any conflict in the code? Where is the problem?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Why have you used `$('[data-toggle=collapse]')`? When I try with `$('#collapse')` it works

Comment: Sorry I was originally data-toggle: "collapse". But I must have mistakenly changed it. http://jsbin.com/vefopuka/1/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and use some other constant value for the button: http://jsfiddle.net/5xbp5/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function togglesidebar(flag) {
        if (flag == -1) {
            $('#xs-menu').toggleClass('show hide');
            $('#lg-menu').toggleClass('show hide');
        } else if (flag == 1) {
            $('#xs-menu').addClass('show').removeClass('hide');
            $('#lg-menu').addClass('hide').removeClass('show');
        } else {
            $('#xs-menu').addClass('hide').removeClass('show');
            $('#lg-menu').addClass('show').removeClass('hide');
        }
    }

    $('#collapse').click(function(){
        togglesidebar(-1);
    });

    $(window).resize(function () {
        windowsize = $(window).width();
        if (windowsize < 768) {
            togglesidebar(1);
        } else {
            togglesidebar(0);
        }
    });

});
```

Your function call `$('#collapse').click(togglesidebar);` without arguments does not seem to call `togglesidebar(flag)`